# Node.js APT Can not get data from mongodbLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try get made an API on node.js , follow some old tutorial , fix some small problem , but I stuck here for two hours , I'm just want to get all the data from mongodbLab , it keep saing

```
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

please help

this is app.js

```
 var express = require('express'),
 songs = require('./routes/route');

var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


app.get('/songs',songs.findAll());
```

this is the route

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var uri = "mongodb://user:XXXXX@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);

// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));

db.once('open', function() {
console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
});

 exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
 db.collection('songs', function(err, collection) {
 collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
  res.send(items);
 });
 });
 };
```

this is error

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe"   
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" app.js
 c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196
    throw new Error(msg);
     ^

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:196:15)
at EventEmitter.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:481:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\app.js:16:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
at startup (node.js:140:18)
at node.js:1001:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line;

```
app.get('/songs',songs.findAll());
```

...calls `findAll` immediately and sets the route to call the return value (which in this case is `Undefined` since the function doesn't return a value)

What you want is;

```
app.get('/songs',songs.findAll);
```

...which sets the route to call the actual function when the get is performed.

Comment: you are right! no error now!
but  when I type localhost:3000/songs
it should print out all the data right?
or I need to write some code to print it out?

Comment: @AweiHsue You should get all the data in the browser due to `res.send(items)`, that should send all items in the response.

Comment: Thank you ! right now it didn't post anything , seems like have some issue at  exports.findAll = function(req, res){...} here , looking for doc to solve it :D